# Error parsing time with TimeSpan.ParseExact

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read in 2 columns from a DataTable that will give me a date and time.

I've tried the line of code:

```
lastRun = DateTime.ParseExact(row["last_run_date"].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
.Add(TimeSpan.ParseExact(row["last_run_time"].ToString().PadLeft(6, '0'), "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

The last_run_date part works OK but the time will not parse correctly.

Comment: What is the value of "last_run_time" that doesn't work?  What specific error are you getting?

Comment: Try "hh" instead of "HH".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For TimeSpan, "HH" is not a valid format specifier - use "hh" instead.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That works a treat. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the two fields and parse them as one:

```
var str = row["last_run_date"].ToString() + " "
        + row["last_run_time"].ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');

lastRun = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMdd HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```